# Problem executing .dtsx package from command line

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, ssis

I am located with command line inside the folder where the .dtsx package is located.
I created this project from within Visual Studio.

Tried solution:

```
DTExec /ISSERVER "EmployeesMigration.dtsx" /SERVER "." /Envreference 2
```

> Error: Description: 'EmployeesMigration.dtsx' is not a valid server package path

```
DTExec /ISSERVER "/EmployeesMigration.dtsx" /SERVER "." /Envreference 2
```

> Error: Missing argument for option "isserver"

Comment: That command line executes the package on the server. Have you published your package to the server? Use the `/F` switch to run an actual .dtsx file

Comment: mmm no I actually just want to run it locally.. I want to open the folder used by my visual studio and where the .dtsx file is located and run it

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid but it works with the /F thanks a lot :)